# How to choose txt file and get the text document data in a variable without uploading in react native?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm very beginning to React-Native.
Pls suggest any package "User want to select a text document and I want to store the document data in a state without uploading into the server.

Actually I tried this package npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-document-picker

After selecting the docunment it will return the content type file path. I can't get the realpath then only I can get the data from the document.

Document picker URL :

`content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc%3D1%3Bdoc%3Dencoded%3DGupAkLwO6gbrFIXXl3YQFSQNCpC6J6gfPyGK5UBhboZKtjNRaSHM8k3vaJw`

Please help me to get the realpath or suggest any npm package according to my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

On selection it will give you a Relative path, something like this content://com.android....... Pass that Relative path to [Stat(filepath)](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/wiki/File-System-Access-API#statpathstringpromisernfetchblobstat) function of the **react-native-fetch-blob** library. The object will return absolute path. Append the path with file:// to use it for further operations.

Comment: It won't work, I think I did mistake in my code. pls check this screenshot sir, Am I correct http://prnt.sc/ozgfyi

Comment: `Error: failed to stat path "null" because it does not exist or it is not a folder`

Comment: Manually enable storage permissions of that app. Don't forget to also add read, write permissions in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Sir Sorry I tired another package `react-native-fs` now i can get the path `/data/user/0/com.whatsappanalysis/cacheWhatsApp/test.txt`

Comment: Did you achieve what you wanted to have?